# Plotting a 3d-function fails

Tags: function, matlab, plot

I try to plot the function f(x,y)=(100-(x^2*y^2))^0.5 in Matlab using

```
x = 0:0.1:10;
y = 0:0.1:5;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y)                            
Z = (100-(X.^2.*Y.^2)).^(0.5)
surf(X,Y,Z)
```

I managed to do so with the following online-plotter: https://math24.pro
and get this result [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b15t9.png)

How can I do that in Matlab? Here I get an error which says that Z is complex instead of real. But I don't get why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Real-Component of a Matrix

Try taking the `real()` component of `z`. The imaginary components are a result of `100-(X.^2.*Y.^2)` computing to a negative value at various `X`, `Y` values. The exponent `0.5` (square root) of a negative number results in imaginary/complex components causing MATLAB to display an error.

[image: 3D Plot]

```
x = 0:0.1:10;
y = 0:0.1:5;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);                            
Z = real((100-(X.^2.*Y.^2)).^(0.5));
surf(X,Y,Z);
```